# Using jQuery plugins in Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Having finished Hartl's great **Rails Tutorial** I'm now working my way through the very good **jQuery - Novice to Ninja** by Castledine and Sharkie.  While I've able to include jquery.js and jquery-ui.js in my rails projects, I'm getting stuck when it comes to adding other jQuery plugins.

I've figured out that when the plugins are hosted on github, I can import them into my project using the command line and:

```
[my rails app]$ rails install [github URL]
```

The plugin gets successfully imported into the /vendor/plugin/ directory where javascript_include_tag can't find them.  This situation prompts 3 questions:

1. Is there a way to import jQuery plugins into my Rails app that puts them into the public/javascripts/ directory where they belong?
2. If the answer to 1 is "no," is there a way to have javascript_include_tag search for scripts in vendor/plugins/?   This seems like bad practice since jQuery scripts are hidden away from the public/javascript/ directory where people would normally look for them.
3. If 1 and 2 are both "no's," is there a more elegant way to move the files from vendor/plugins/ than $mv or copying and pasting?

Note: Through web searching I've come across 37signals' sprokets gem at http://getsprockets.org/ which seems like it might be useful at some point but beyond my current needs and understanding.

Grateful for any thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal practice is to download a minified version of the plugin you'd like to use and save it in the `public/javascripts` directory.

`rails install` is for Rails plugins, not jQuery plugins.

Comment: Very cool.  Both your answers helped me put what I've figured out into a wider context.

Answer (score 8):

In current rails version the directory would be

```
/vendor/assets/javascripts
```

Comment: This is now the correct place to put them if you're using the asset pipeline which is basically sprockets in rails with a bunch of added convenience and functionality (there's very little reason not to use it).  Many jQuery plugins you can even include as a gem, and the asset pipeline will find the assets from the gem (see masonry-rails gem, for instance).  A new development is talk about replacing those kind of asset library gems with Twitter's 'bower'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insistent on using rails install you could write a rake or thor task to copy the files for you.

You could also try a symlink between the public/javascripts directory and the download directory so the stylesheet tag can just access it.